# Why can't you assign multiple columns that are not the same name as in the original pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

```
     odds_ft_home_team_win  odds_ft_draw  odds_ft_away_team_win
0                 0.850212      0.100281               0.049506
1                 0.081114      0.146371               0.772515
2                 0.486790      0.266734               0.246476
3                 0.355737      0.301008               0.343255
4                 0.294952      0.299490               0.405559
```

This is a dataframe `prob_odds` I want to assign to my previous data-frame `df`.

```
df.loc[:,["w","d","a"]]=prob_odds
```

As you can see I want the new columns to have a different name than in the original dataframe. This returns a data-frame that has the columns `"w","d","a"` with NA values. If I change the names of the columns in the `prob_odds` Data-Frame to match the names in the `df` the assignment works. Why is that? What is the way to go around this so that you can assign new columns without having to rename the old ones beforehand.

Comment: How would pandas know where to put which values, if not by row and column name?

Comment: Well the prob_odds has three columns. I assumed that the assignment would take the three columns in order.

Comment: when assign with an index, drop the column index will be fine, `df.loc[:,["w","d","a"]]=prob_odds.values`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, just without `.loc` (because `.loc` would search for existing indexes and columns to operate on):

```
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1 * np.ones(N), 'b': 2 * np.ones(N)})
df[['c', 'd']] = pd.DataFrame({'x': 3 * np.ones(N), 'y': 4 * np.ones(N)})

df
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
5  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
6  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
7  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
8  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
9  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

P.S. To match your naming, `df[["w","d","a"]] = prob_odds` should work